# iOS Test build closes after opening

Tags: ios, google-fabric, fabric-beta

When opening test builds on iOS the app closes immediately after the launch screen. I've implemented `Crashlytics` as well but no crash reports come up.

Or does `Crashlytics` not report crashes from 3rd party libraries maybe or do I need to implement something for that?

I've narrowed the crash down to one of the 3rd party libraries but not sure on what it crashes.

Comment: How you have installed the test build in a device? from test flight or manual install using Xcode?

Comment: @AtulParmar Enterprise build, I've tested with Fabric Beta and normal .ipa export, both crash.

Comment: I think application certificate may expire, check it once.

Comment: @AtulParmar Profile & certificate were just created and still valid, and sometimes the app opens fine but 9 out of 10 times it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find the exact reason of crash is to connect your device to mac and look for the logs in console for the specific time when you launch the app.

Also I would recommend to check your 'Keychain Access' for 'Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority' cert on your mac (which is used to build .ipa). Right click on it and choose 'Get info'. Looks for 'When using this certificate' should be set to 'Use System Defaults'